# Track Email Category change in public shared folder only if I make the change

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have code to track changes in the Category of emails in a Public (Shared) Folder.

I have set up the code to be able to switch it "on/off", and this code is in ThisOutlookSession:

```vb
Private WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.Items

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim prompt As String
    prompt = Item.Categories
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
        'do stuff
    End If
End Sub

Sub TriggerOn()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myOlItems = Outlook.Session.Folders("SampleMailBox").Folders("Inbox").Items
End Sub

Sub TriggerOff()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myOlItems = Nothing
End Sub
```

Since this a Public Shared Folder, if any other user makes a change, the code will be triggered.

I want to track only the changes that I make.

Comment: I actually needed it to track public changes, can you help me figure out to make say in the message box who changed it?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [CurrentUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869341(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Namespace class. The property returns the display name of the currently logged-on user as a Recipient object. So, if it is you, you can run the code (display a message box and etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I think that could be a start. But how do I define it to trigger if the change is made by the `.CurrentUser`?

Comment: In the ItemChange event handler you may check the CurrentUser - whether it is you and only then display a message box.

Comment: You mean after the line `myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)` to add `If Outlook.Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI") = Outlook.Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI").CurrentUser Then`? A bit more help please :)

Comment: Nope. If CurrentUser == "Your Name" then display a dialog.

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried as you have suggested but testing the result that I get when using `Msgbox Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser` after the `myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object` line but I would get my name even when I am not the one who made the change. Kindly assist

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of the `PR_LAST_xyz` properties (`PR_LAST_MODIFIER_NAME`, `PR_LAST_MODIFIER_ENTRYID`, etc.) These properties can be accessed using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. Take a look at the messages with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button) to see the available properties and their values as well as the property DASL names that you will need to use when calling `GetProperty`.

Another solution would be to use `MailItem.Write` event. If you assume that the category can be modified from the right click on the message only and a message must be selected before it is modified, you can track the `Explorer.SelectionChange` event, set up event sinks on the selected messages, and track the `MailItem.Write` event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that OutlookSpy is an option as it requires installation (something I cannot do at the office). Kindly elaborate on how I can track the username from the `Explorer.SelectionChange ` :)

Comment: I suggested OutlookSpy for you to see what is available. Your code (which will end up using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty) will not need OutlookSpy at run time is any way. As a test, try to read the PR_LAST_MODIFIER_NAME (DASL name "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3FFA001F"). Would I would do is read the PR_LAST_MODIFIER_ENTRYID, convert it to a hex string using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString, then compare that entry id to the entry of the current user (Application.Session.CurrentUser.EntryID) using Namespace.CompareEntryIDs

Comment: PR_LAST_MODIFIER_ENTRYID DASL name is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3FFB0102"